# ASP doesn't load all entities when getting a database record

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a record in database of a class:

```
public class Wallet
{
    public Wallet()
    {
    }

    public Wallet(string userName, CurrencySellPrices currencySellPrices, CurrencyAmounts currencyAmounts, double availableMoney)
    {
        UserName = userName;
        CurrencySellPrices = currencySellPrices;
        CurrencyAmounts = currencyAmounts;
        AvailableMoney = availableMoney;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public CurrencySellPrices CurrencySellPrices { get; set; }
    public CurrencyAmounts CurrencyAmounts { get; set; }
    public double AvailableMoney { get; set; }

}
```

and when I try to pick a record with this code:

```
public ActionResult Exchange()
    {
        var username = User.Identity.GetUserName();
        var model = _db.Wallets.ToList().Find(r=>r.UserName==username);
        return View(model);
    }
```

It gets the right record, but objects of classes CurrenciesSellPrices and CurrencyAmounts are null. In the database they are proper records.

Classes look like this:

```
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UsdAmount { get; set; }
    public int EurAmount { get; set; }
    public int ChfAmount { get; set; }
    public int RubAmount { get; set; }
    public int CzkAmount { get; set; }
    public int GbpAmount { get; set; }
}

public class CurrencySellPrices
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double UsdSellPrice { get; set; }
    public double EurSellPrice { get; set; }
    public double ChfSellPrice { get; set; }
    public double RubSellPrice { get; set; }
    public double CzkSellPrice { get; set; }
    public double GbpSellPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Am I missing something im my classes so they aren't properly loaded from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EntityFramework doesn't load related entities automatically if it's not explicitly told.

You can achieve the expected result with [Eager Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx).

```
var model = _db.Wallets
                .Include(wallet => wallet.CurrencySellPrices)
                .Include(wallet => wallet.CurrencyAmounts)
                .Find(r => r.UserName == username)
                .ToList();
```

I've also switch the order of **Find** and **ToList** in order to extract only the chosen entity and not to load them all and then filter the one you need.

Comment: That was it, Thank You very much for Your Answer @OrelEraki !

Answer (score 0):

You should tell entity framework to load them, It's popular behavior of entity framework called lazy loading " google it"
your code should look something like this

```
_db.Wallets.Include(w => w.CurrenciesSellPrices)
            .Include(w => w.CurrencyAmounts)
            .ToList().Find(r=>r.UserName==username);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your entities, try this:

```
_db.Wallets
    .Include(nameof(Wallets.CurrencySellPrices))
    .Include(nameof(Wallets.CurrencyAmounts))
    .Find(r=>r.UserName==username)
    .ToList();

_db.Wallets
    .Include(wallet => wallet.CurrencySellPrices)
    .Include(wallet => wallet.CurrencyAmounts)
    .Find(r=>r.UserName==username)
    .ToList();
```

The former is done by including the property via name, the latter is done including the property via a LINQ expression. Both will give the same result.

As the name suggests, `Include` includes relations when retrieving the data via Entity Framework.